# Handle post (from iOS) with image in asp.net server

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net-mvc-4, afnetworking-2

First, the question briefly:
What I should write in the action parameters for handling the image sent and how to handle data to get the image of it?

What I did is:

1. Image in iOS converted to NSData (which is a Byte array data if I'm not wrong.
2. Using AFNetworking to post: to strings that I need in params dict and the image data in
       [formData appendWith...].

On the server side, how should my action look like?
Currently it's:

```
    Public JsonResult HandleData (string x, string y, ???????????) {}
```

The to strings will come from the parameters dictionary but what do I need to do to get the image data and reverse it back to real image?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Yep.. Doesn't seem to be the right way.  I saw solutions using Request.context... but I did't understand how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. The solution was very simple use in *HttpPostedFileBase*.

Just added another parameter to my method (HttpPostedFileBase file) and then:

```
if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
```

Hope it will be useful for poeple like me that are drowning in much more complex solution out there...